# Accessing Magnolia TemplatingFunctions from inside a controller

Tags: java, magnolia

Is it possible to serve different experiences depending on whether the user is in edit mode? I've noticed that the following method exists; however it is not static:

```
info.magnolia.templating.functions.TemplatingFunctions.isEditMode()
```

Is there a way to access the isEditMode() method from inside a controller? Is an instance of it defined somewhere which can be accessed? I imagine that creating a new instance of the `TemplatingFunctions` class won't help ...

I've looked at using `@Inject`; however I keep getting issues on injection of all parameters.

```
@Inject
public ModelAndView renderView(Model model, Node node, TemplatingFunctions templatingFunctions) throws RepositoryException {
    if (templatingFunctions.isEditMode()) {

    }
}
```

Comment: @ducaz035 any thoughts about this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I checked what that method does, I found out that its a combination of two functions.

```
Components.getComponent(ServerConfiguration.class).isAdmin()
```

and

```
aggregationStateProvider.get().isPreviewMode()
```

It seems that you should be injecting a provider to know if user is in preview mode

```
Provider<AggregationState> aggregationStateProvider
```

As a general remark, one may understand if a component is injectable or not from the related modules configuration which is under `myModule/src/main/resources/META-INF/mymodule.xml`. If a component is listed there, then is it injectable in other classes. For instance you should have no problems injecting a type of `TemplatinFunctions` because it is indeed defined as;

```
<component>
  <type>info.magnolia.templating.functions.TemplatingFunctions</type>
  <implementation>info.magnolia.templating.functions.TemplatingFunctions</implementation>
  <scope>singleton</scope>
</component>
```

Further reading can be found at https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Dependency+injection+and+inversion+of+control

Hope this helps,

Comment: This definitely helped. The way we did it is without using an @Autowire or @Inject service, but instead using `TemplatingFunctions templatingFunctions = Components.getComponent(TemplatingFunctions.class);`

Comment: If you can get it with Components.getComponent(), then injecting it should have no problem as well. I suspect that other fields might not be injectable in that case :) but glad that helped